# CMake Why cannot use .exe for custom target

Tags: cmake, exe

Here is the *CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project("cmake_oneoneone")
add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
set(library_name liba CACHE string "This variable is the library name")
add_library(${library_name} STATIC src/liba.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${library_name})
include_directories(include)
add_custom_target(run_main
              COMMAND ./main
              DEPENDS main
              )
```

The output is:

```
~/workspace/cmake_test/build$ make run_main
[ 50%] Built target liba
[100%] Built target main 
Hello world!
[100%] Built target run_main
```

but if I change executable to .exe

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project("cmake_oneoneone")
add_executable(main.exe src/main.cpp)
set(library_name liba CACHE string "This variable is the library name")
add_library(${library_name} STATIC src/liba.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main.exe ${library_name})
include_directories(include)
add_custom_target(run_main
              COMMAND ./main.exe
              DEPENDS main.exe
              )

~/workspace/cmake_training/build$ make run_main
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `../main.exe', needed by `CMakeFiles/run_main'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/run_main.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/run_main.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [run_main] Error 2
```

I tried either Linux and Windows on both the CMake behaves the same.

Comment: I know it doesn't help you, but why do you want to add .exe while non-exe version does its work?

Comment: I thought it doesn't add exe until specified.

Comment: What would make CMake platform dependant which  would be agains CMake's philosophy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation of the [ADD_EXECUTABLE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:add_executable) command, you can figure out that CMake automatically adds the extension .exe to your executable in case that you are generating it in a Windows environment. If you are in Linux, obviously generate a .exe has no sense:

> Adds an executable target called  to be built from the source files listed in the command invocation. The  corresponds to the logical target name and must be globally unique within a project. The actual file name of the executable built is constructed based on conventions of the native platform (such as .exe or just ).

So you do not have to add the .exe at the end of the name of your executable.

Comment: O, right! I could have look it up myself. Sorry for troubling. Thanks! But IMHO that's bad that CMake does not warn you about that in any way.

Comment: No worries @mastier! CMake documentation could be a bit tricky at the beginning but I am pretty sure that you will become more comfortable over time.

Comment: hope so, too much implicit magic is never a good idea or it is just pythonic me ;-)